# How to visualise Open Trace Format files in ITAC GUI

Tags: mpi, trace, itac

I have trace of an MPI application collected in Open Trace Format, (version 2) is it possible to visualize and interpret the trace results in GUI application like ITAC. I was looking for The Trace Map and Event timeline charts to be visualized for the trace available. I am on a linux machine. I am able to load Structured Trace Format (STF) files without issues. Is there a similar way to load the Open Trace Format to ITAC?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the only GUI to visualize OTF2 traces is [Vampir](https://vampir.eu/). It's pretty good. It's a commercial tool, but a free demo version is available. Many HPC centers have it installed, too.